# CSS nth of-type or child not working with custom elements inside another custom element

Tags: html, css

I am creating a layout with custom elements inside custom elements and having problems with css:nth. I am adding icons in content:before but they all display the same icon. Here is the code

First try CSS code, using nth-of-type(number):

```
custom-div:nth-of-type(1):before {content:url('1.svg');}
custom-div:nth-of-type(2):before {content:url('2.svg');}
custom-div:nth-of-type(3):before {content:url('3.svg');}
```

Second try CSS code, using child(number):

```
custom-div:nth-of-type(1):before {content:url('1.svg');}
custom-div:nth-of-type(2):before {content:url('2.svg');}
custom-div:nth-of-type(3):before {content:url('3.svg');}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<another-div><custom-div> text 1 </custom-div></another-div>
<another-div><custom-div> text 2 </custom-div></another-div>
<another-div><custom-div> text 3 </custom-div></another-div>
```

As you can see, what I want is to display icons different icons to each custom-div, but the only result I am getting is that the same icon 1.svg is being displayed for all 3 custom divs. no matter what I do

EDIT: forgot to say that the custom-div is inside another-div both with custom elements names

Comment: Do you have double-checked that the icons are different? 

Comment: yes sir I checked that

Comment: why use custom divs to just add content svg? Try using normal img tag

Comment: *Here is the HTML* --> I am pretty sure it's not the *real* HTML code

Comment: I think I forgot something so I will edit the question

Comment: Check this out it works fine with SVGs too: [svg jsfiddle file](https://jsfiddle.net/yh5xbL48/4/)

Comment: @Noquierona it still works the same in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ar7noy1/2/)

Comment: Tanishq you are using the same image for all, I need different images on all 3

Comment: hmm.... let me see

Comment: Alright found the problem, ill post an answer

Comment: thanks Tanishq, I am loosing my hair with this :)

Comment: @Noquierona actually could you wait for 11mins, I've got a cooldown of 30 minutes to answer...

Comment: no problem, I will go for a pizza

Comment: @Noquierona you can check the answer now, I've posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to do it an addition to @TanishqS.

You can still use the `custom-div` with:

```css
another-div:nth-of-type(1) custom-div::before { content: url("https://placehold.co/50"); }
another-div:nth-of-type(2) custom-div::before { content: url("https://placehold.co/80"); }
another-div:nth-of-type(3) custom-div::before { content: url("https://placehold.co/100"); }
```

```html
<another-div><custom-div> text 1 </custom-div></another-div>
<another-div><custom-div> text 2 </custom-div></another-div>
<another-div><custom-div> text 3 </custom-div></another-div>
```

Comment: For all users having the same problem, this solution works best if you by some readon add more another-div elements, it is safer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `:nth-of-type` on the child component (`custom-div`) itself rather than on the parent component (`another-div`)

This should work for you:

```css
another-div:nth-of-type(1) custom-div::before {
content: url("https://img.cdn4dd.com/s/media/photosV2/1954ba82-d91f-43a2-8838-767fd2ad386f-retina-large.svg");
}

another-div:nth-of-type(2) custom-div::before {
content: url("https://img.cdn4dd.com/s/media/photosV2/edf12308-afd7-427e-b4d4-7e78c3efce01-retina-large.svg");
}

another-div:nth-of-type(3) custom-div::before {
content: url("https://img.cdn4dd.com/s/media/photosV2/0d63d52b-ff6f-4c39-8b52-f6c605ce38dc-retina-large.svg");
}
```

```html
<another-div>
  <custom-div> text 1 </custom-div>
</another-div>
<another-div>
  <custom-div> text 2 </custom-div>
</another-div>
<another-div>
  <custom-div> text 3 </custom-div>
</another-div>
```

Comment: There is no mention of the `:nth-child` pseudoselector in the question. As well, this does not achieve the goal of placing the generated content before the `<custom-div>` element.

Comment: @miken32 I appreciate your correction, but I never used `:nth-child`

Comment: The first sentence of your answer?

Comment: ...there you go

Comment: But the real problem is your generated content is in a completely different place to what they are looking for.

Comment: I had a talk about this problem and it seems that my answer fixed the problem so I posted this answer, could you explain where the problem is coming from?

Comment: It's fine after your edit; I hadn't noticed you'd fixed it after my first comment. Though now it's the same as the OP's self-answer.